# jQuery MultiFile - how to clear / reset?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, reset, multifile-uploader

I'm using the jQuery multi-file upload plugin found here:
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

I don't see in any of the examples though a way to "reset" the file-picker, 
clearing out any currently selected items.

Any one know how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I uploaded my [multi-file here](http://www.box.net/shared/vf1g19gl1e). 
I wound up rolling my own, because I could not get this plug-in to work.

I had to cull a lot out of the file that was specific to the client, but the important stuff for the file upload should all be there. I did NOT include the upload library for parsing the form submission, just the client code for creating a multi-file upload UI, for what it is. It's all provided as is.

Hope it may help somebody!

Comment: I have been having a lot of problems with this plugin as well.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation included in the download.  Also noted on the [Upload](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Uploading) documentation page (scroll to bottom, under AJAX).

> How do I reset the control?
>
> To reset the file selections, just make the following call:
>
> $('input:file').MultiFile('reset')

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I missed that at the bottom of the page down there. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work... even though my selector does return items. Ah well, on to something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type=file]").wrap("<div id='fileWrapper'/>");
$("#fileWrapper").append("<div id='duplicateFile' style='display:none'>"+$("#fileWrapper").html()+"</div>");
$("#fileWrapper").html($("#duplicateFile").html());
```

Answer (score -1):

This also works..

```
$('.MultiFile-list').find('a').click();
```